# Is it possible to force the size of a ConstraintLayout child to zero?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

`android:layout_height="0dp"` seems to be interpreted as `match_constraints`.

I'd like to force the height of a TextView to 0 programmatically.I'd like to avoid doing textView.setVisibility(GONE) in order to avoid having to define goneMargins everywhere.

Is it possible to specify that a child is still visible but has a height of 0 ?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to happen when the view's height is set to zero. Should other view shift in response and how so? Or do you want everything to stay in place?

Comment: I want the other views to follow their constraints. In my case, it's going to be a shift since they are aligned on top of the view that needs to disappear. But really, it's just a general case. It's like putting 42dp or 666dp, I just want it to be 0dp.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove bottom constraints
`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` from your TextView then the following should work:

```
binding.your_textview.layoutParams.height = 0
binding.your_textview.requestLayout()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set its size to `1` in code or `1px` in xml and also make it invisible. One pixel is not noticeable and `ConstraintLayout` still does not take it for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.
This should be enough/removing all constraints while the width/height attribute still being 0dp.

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.clear(id_of_the_view);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Comment: That would work but then the constraints won't work anymore. The point of setting the dimensions to 0 is precisely to avoid changing the constraints

Comment: Well I am afraid you can't have a cake and eat it too. Maybe post XML code so it can be better understood what you are trying to do.